# String to Enum out of enum value

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum like this

```
public enum People {
    OUT("People out"),
    IN("People in");

    private final String name;

   // **StageName**(String name) {
   People(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

An I want to get the Enum type given a value, something like :

```
People.getEnumValueOf("People out")
```

And that should return an enum `People.OUT`

How do I do that?

Comment: Any of the top three answers on the question @daniu linked to will solve your problem.

Comment: Almost `People.valueOf(name.toUpperCase().replace("PEOPLE ", ""));`